# jquery mobile swipe delay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement a simple swipe for a mobile app in my internship. I first made an example before I implement it to my project. When I swipe to the left, I would be redirected to the next page. However, when I try to swipe to the right to go back to the previous page, it takes me about 4 tries to go back.

index.html

```
      *{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    div{
        max-width: 1024px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 768px;
        background: green;
    }


    <div></div>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4 
/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5
/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("div").on("swipeleft",function(){
     window.location = "nextpage.html";
    });

    });

</script>
```

nextpage.html

```
   *{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

     div{
        max-width: 1024px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 768px;
        background: blue;
    }

    <div></div>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4 
/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5
/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("div").on("swiperight",function(){
     window.location = "index.html";
    });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: the `div` used in your jquery selector maybe causing that.. Try giving a class to the outermost div and then use that to delegate the `swiperight` event

Comment: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Basic_swipe.html: You can have a look at this JS .. maybe it will be useful to you

Comment: @Renboy - I think you are missing the first line of your script block $(document).ready(function () {....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adjusting the swipe thresholds to make the right swipe more sensitive? I'm guessing it has to do with your right swipe being slightly angled or shorter (probably just enough to fall outside of the thresholds).

Try adding the below lines before the swipe handlers on your 2nd page. Try changing the thresholds a lot more if your swipe still isn't recognized.

```
// this is the distance you have to drag your finger across to be recognized as a swipe - default is 30px. Decrease this.
$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 10;
// this is the amount of vertical leeway you get before your horizontal swipe is NOT treated as a horizontal swipe - default is 75px. Increase this.
$.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = 100;
// this is the amount of time you get to drag your finger across and make the thresholds - default is 1000 = 1s. Increase this.
$.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold = 2000;
```

Comment: I used another library but I will try this next time, Thanks